# Pass scopes in @react-keycloak/ssr lib

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keycloak

I am using the library @react-keycloak/ssr in my next js project but i can't find a way to pass scopes. Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! Did you found a way of doing this?

Comment: No, sorry I spent long time searching about this and found nothing, my conclusion: there is not a way of do it with that lib

Comment: Hi! I've found a way. It's using the login method, and passnig the `scope` param there. It's nowhere documented, that's why I found it sad

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is to late but I end up here now. I will share the solution that was suggested in a github issue and works for me.

You need to add the following init option to the Provider:

```
<SSRKeycloakProvider
        ...
        initOptions={{onLoad: 'check-sso'}}
        >
```

and then where you call the login method, pass the scope.

```
keycloak?.login({ scope: 'my-scopes' });
```

Here is the link to original response:https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/issues/127